# How to make the clearTimeout fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an SVG with `<uses>` not and when you touch one of them a `touchstart` events fires. If they move a `touchmove` event fires that has a timer. On `touchend` the timer is cleared before the value is supposed to change. However, it changes anyway.

The results of this are that the `IsDraggingUnit` is set to `true` even after the `touchend` is fired. I tested with an `alert` and it is firing successfully when ending your touch on the element.

```js
var IsDraggingUnit = false;
var timeOutClear;

$('#Selected_Items use').on("touchstart", function(event) {
  IsDraggingUnit = false;
  $('#test > p').text(IsDraggingUnit);

  $(this).on("touchmove", function(event) {
    timeOutClear = setTimeout(function() {
      IsDraggingUnit = true;
      $('#test > p').text(IsDraggingUnit);
    }, 500);
  });

  $(this).on("touchend", function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeOutClear);
    if (IsDraggingUnit == false) {
      fnPlotShow($(this), bookingRental, bookingExists)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are nesting the `touchmove` and `touchend` events within the `touchstart` event. Therefore on subsequent `touchstart` occurrences each event fires multiple times and the reference to the original timeout gets lost and `clearTimeout()` does not clear them all.

To fix this, do not make the event handlers nested, and don't forget to set `isDraggingUnit` back to `false` on `touchend`

```js
var isDraggingUnit = false, timeOutReference;

$('#Selected_Items use').on({
  touchstart: function(event) {
    isDraggingUnit = false;
    $('#test > p').text(isDraggingUnit);
  },
  touchmove: function(event) {
    timeOutReference = setTimeout(function() {
      isDraggingUnit = true;
      $('#test > p').text(isDraggingUnit);
    }, 500);
  },
  touchend: function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeOutReference);
    if (!isDraggingUnit) {
      fnPlotShow($(this), bookingRental, bookingExists)
    }
    isDraggingUnit = false;
  }
});
```

Also note that your question states the SVG holds `<uses>` nodes, yet you select `use`. I assume this is just a typo in the question, though, as it wouldn't work at all if there was a mismatch there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. The same problem still exists.

Comment: In which case can you create a working example of the issue in your question so that we can debug the whole thing.

Comment: It works with jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/yh73acwe/2/

Just not the code above. 

Edit: Doesn't work as intended on it either.